# Invoking @selector methods between classes

Tags: iphone

I see many Objective-C/Cocoa SDK apis where you can specify a target and an action that will get called back.

I want to do the same in two of my classes but when I store the passed in selector and later try to invoke it, I get the exception,

> "unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance"

I pass off to ClassB the target and action like this:

```
[myClassB doSomething:self action:@selector(anAction:)];
```

ClassB is declared and implemented as this:

```
@interface ClassB
{
   id  target;
   SEL targetAction;
}

@implementation ClassB 

-(void)theWork {
if ( [target respondsToSelector:targetAction] ) 
{
    [target targetAction];
}
}
```

During the build process, I also get the following warning:

> no '-targetAction' method found

How can I invoke the target action that was supplied?

What I want to achieve is similar to this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
          target:self 
          action:@selector(cancelItem:)];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[target targetAction];
```

means to run the method called targetAction.

you want

```
[target performSelector:targetAction];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the selector name in your ivar:

```
ClassB *b = [[ClassB alloc] init];
SomeOtherClass *a = [[SomeOtherClass alloc] init];

// next two lines require properties to be declared
b.target = a;
b.targetAction = @selector(doTask:);
```

Now in ClassB you can invoke method on a with

```
[target performSelector:targetAction withObject:someObject];
```

That would invoke

```
- (void)doTask:(id)object
```

on class SomeOtherClass passing someObject to it.